# How to pass a list of strings from python to shell script?

Tags: python, bash, list, shell, parameters

I need to pass a list of strings from python to shell script.

**Goal:**
Inside the Shell script,

1)The shell script should accept that list of strings which is passed as a parameter.

2)I need to loop that list and print the strings inside the loop.

What I had tried:

*main.py*

```
import subprocess
ssh_key_path = #KEY_PATH
ip_address = #BASTION_IP
Details = #Somedata
list_1 = ["apple","banana","carrot"]
script = subprocess.call([sh,fruits.sh,ssh_key_path,ip_address,Details,list_1])
```

*fruits.sh*

```
ssh -i $1 ubuntu@$2 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no << EOF
   printf $3 >/home/Details.txt
   fruits = $4
   for i in $4; do
     echo "$i"
   done
   echo "Success" 
EOF
```

**Output** from fruits.sh:(Expected Output)

```
apple
banana
carrot
Success
```

**Error**:
expected str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not list.

So,How to pass the list to shell script and execute inside it.?

Answer (score 1):

Just join with spaces.  For example:

`test.py`

```
import subprocess

fruits = ["apple","banana","carrot"]

subprocess.call(["sh", "test.sh", "hello", " ".join(fruits)])
```

`test.sh`

```
echo "greeting: $1"

for i in $2
do
    echo "fruit: $i"
done
```

Output:

```
greeting: hello
fruit: apple
fruit: banana
fruit: carrot
```

The basic point here is that you are passing a single string argument, and your shell script is then splitting it as required.

But if you cannot use space as a separator, then you will have to use multiple arguments. For example:

`test.py`

```
import subprocess

fruits = ["green apple", "yellow banana", "orange carrot"]

subprocess.call(["sh", "./test.sh", "hello"] + fruits)
```

`test.sh`

```
echo "greeting: $1"

shift

for i in "$@"
do
    echo "fruit: $i"
done
```

output:

```
greeting: hello
fruit: green apple
fruit: yellow banana
fruit: orange carrot
```

Here the `shift` in the shell script will drop the first argument from the argument list, so that the `"$@"` will loop over the remaining arguments. (Repeat `shift` as many times as necessary.)